# Using back reference in preg_replace in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have some text in the format:

```
[This is some text]
```

I would like to convert it as:

```
{This is some text}
```

Can I do it using back reference with preg_replace function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back-references aren't appropriate or required here. You can simply use group matching and replacement, like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', '{$1}', $string);
```

Example: http://3v4l.org/NNn35

Comment: His expected result uses braces, not brackets.